# How to get the last birthday year with the date of birth (Python)

Tags: python

I am want to get the last year that someone celebrated his birthday
with his date of birth.

example:

```
if my date of birth is 12/12/1971        
and the date know is 4/12/2021   
so my last birthday was in 12/12/2020       
so the year is equal to 2020
```

example2:

```
if my date of birth is 04/04/2005        
and the date know is 4/12/2021   
so my last birthday was in 04/04/2021       
so the year is equal to 2021
```

this is my code:

```
def selfYear(birthdate):
    today = date.today()
    birthday = birthdate[0]
    birthmonth = birthdate[1]
    birthyear = birthdate[2]
    currentDate = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    currentDate.split('-')
```

someone can help me figer this out

Comment: How does your code relate to the problem?

Comment: Build your birthday for this year; if it is after today, back up a year.

Comment: when i think of it its not

Comment: you can literally just pass your DOB as string and replace the year via `birthdate.replace(birthday.split('-')[-1], time.strftime('%Y'))` (replace '-' with anything with which date will be seperated like dd-mm--yy or dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 1):

Compute the current year birthday date, and check if it's already done or not, then return the good year value

```
def last_birthday(birthdate):
    today = date.today()
    if birthdate.replace(year=today.year) <= today:
        return today.year
    return today.year - 1


print(last_birthday(date(1971, 12, 12)))  # 2020
print(last_birthday(date(2005, 4, 4)))  # 2021
```

---

With the auto conversion `True -> 1, False -> 0` you could do

```
def last_birthday(birthdate):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - (birthdate.replace(year=today.year) > today)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date.replace` method.

```
def last_birthday(birthday:date):
   current_year = date.today().year
   birthday.replace(year=current_year)
   if birthday > date.today():
       birthday.replace(year=current_year-1)
   return birthday.year
```

Comment: Request was for the year, not the date.

Comment: Corrected. I still think most cases would use the entire date, so I left the logic the same.